# Ways of overidding core phtml files magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need confirmation as to are there different methods of overriding the core phtml files in magento 2.

I referred this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601248/how-to-replace-phtml-files-in-magento-2-0

1) Are **'Custom theme'** and **'Custom Module'** 2 different ways of overriding phtml files?

2) I need an example for the same.

Comment: If your module need some change to core phtml, definitely you need to overwrite inside your module. Which one you tried?

Comment: im trying to override core phtml template using my custom theme which is in app/design...need to override magento_catalog